# what's the addressing term for L5-7 OSI layers?

Tags: json, web, osi

L2 use 6 bytes MAC for device addressing; L3 use IPv4 for logical network addressing, and IPv6 also encapsulate MAC address; L4 use socket(IP + Port) for software addressing.
So, what's the addressing entity term for L5~L7.
Does URL, REST API, json schema belong to this kind of concept?

Answer (score 1):

You can't shoehorn the Internet Protocol suite into the OSI model. IP was developed before the OSI model, and uses a different world view. The two worlds have learned things from each other, but it is very difficult to compare them.

For instance, Layer 2 is a local communication protocol, while Layer 3 allows for routing between local networking environments. IP obviously spans all of Layer 2 and most of Layer 3, while not addressing many of the things that OSI does. IP is a datagram protocol without retransmission, while OSI Layer 2 LAPB implements retransmission.